# Explain coding written for php function

Tags: php

I am not able to get the code written of these function.Can any one explain flow and process.
The code written in the t() function calling, after comment

```
function t($function)
{
    $t0 = microtime(true);
    $result = $function();
    echo " ** time = ", round((microtime(true) - $t0) * 1000, 2), "ms\r\n";
    return $result;
}

// Do a ton of lookups

t(function() use ($ipc) {
    for($i=0; $i<256; $i++)
    {
        $ipc->lookup("$i.0.0.0"); 
        $ipc->lookup("$i.$i.0.0"); 
        $ipc->lookup("$i.$i.$i.0"); 
        $ipc->lookup("$i.$i.$i.$i"); 
        $ipc->lookup("0.$i.$i.$i"); 
        $ipc->lookup("0.0.$i.$i"); 
        $ipc->lookup("0.0.0.$i"); 
    }

    for($i=0; $i<25000; $i++)
        $ipc->lookup(implode('.', array(rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255))));
});
```

Comment: interesting coding style. probably rare to encounter this.

Comment: Do you have trouble understanding the code as such or do you just dont understand the `function() use() {` part. The latter is an [Anonymous Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: t() is just a wrapper function that allow to automatically print the execution time of the function passed in parameter. The purpose of t is to get the microtime, run a given function, and finally get again the microtime to calculate the diff.

Comment: I am not able to understand the function in function, actually whole flow

Comment: what is t(function() use ($ipc)), how it works, any other related eg